# Probability distribution of log(1+exp(X)) for Gaussian RV

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am interested in the theory of random variables $Y$ of the form $Y = \log(1+\exp(X))$ with Gaussian $X\sim\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

In particular, I'm interested in results on the cumulative distribution function, the moment generating function, and the cumulant generating function.

What might be suitable keywords to find discussions of these probability distributions / random variables?

I know that for $x\to\pm\infty$, I can approximate $Y$ as either $Y=X$ or $Y=0$, respectively. Maybe there exist bounds on the stochastic properties of $Y$ in terms of these approximations?

Comment: Since $f(x)= \log(1+\exp(x))$ is one-to-one, we can directly calculate the cumulative distribution function of $Y$ as $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq \log(e^y - 1)) = \Phi(( \log(e^y-1) - \mu)/\sigma)$, where $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.